# What semantic notions underlie 駁 (to rebut) with 馬 (horses) and/or 爻 (I Ching's hexagrams)?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

I'm trying to understand the etymology for definition 3 (to rebut) below in [駁 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A7%81). [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E9%A7%81#):

[image]

> ### Han character
>
> **駁** (*radical 187,* [馬](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E9%A6%AC)+4, 14 strokes, *[cangjie input](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_Cangjie)* 尸火大大 ([SFKK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_Cangjie/s)), *[four-corner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_four_corner)* [74340](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_four_corner/7), *[composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_description_languages#Ideographic_Description_Sequences)* ⿰[馬](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A6%AC)[爻](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%88%BB))
>
> [豹](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Chinese/%E8%B1%B9&action=edit&redlink=1) (*OC *preːwɢs*, “[leopard](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leopard)”) is its exopassive derivative, literally meaning, "the spotted one".
>
> ### Definitions
>
> 1. (of a [horse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horse)'s [fur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fur)) [variegated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/variegated)
> 2. [mixed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mixed); [heterogenous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heterogenous)
> 3. to [refute](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/refute); to [rebut](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rebut)
> 4. to [transport](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transport) by [barge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barge)
> 5. [barge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barge)
> 6. [suddenly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suddenly)

I don't understand how 馬 or definition 1 (variegated horse's fur) relates to definition 3. So I looked up [爻 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%88%BB), but I also don't understand how the I Ching's hexagram relates. I'm too addled to continue!

> 1. a figure composed of six stacked horizontal lines; a [hexagram](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hexagram) of the [I Ching](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/I_Ching)

Answer (score 3):

Two notes:

- The original meaning of 「爻」 is *criss-cross patterns*, rather than *I-Ching hexagrams*;
- 「爻」 provides a *phonetic hint* to 「駁」.

---

「駁」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*pˤrawk/**, *patterend/variegated horse fur*) is composed of semantic 「馬」 (*horse*) and phonetic 「爻」 (**/*N-kˤraw/**). 「爻」 (*criss-cross patterns*) simultaneously provides a meaning hint.

The semantic extension is as follows:

1. *Variegated horse fur*
2. *Impure/mixed colours and patterns* (looking like a jumbled mess)
3. *To distinguish, rectify* (e.g. in the process of sorting out a jumbled mess, correcting what is chaotic/wrong)
4. *To rebut* (e.g. *to refute falsehoods, denounce wrongdoing*)

---

**References:**

- [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%A7%81)
- 《漢語大詞典》